# Can't solve OLSR error on ns-2.35 in ubuntu14.04

Tags: ns2

After successfully applied /home/uday/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/umolsr-ns235_v1.0-2014.patch then

```
*./install
In file included from trace/cmu-trace.cc:57:0:
./dymoum/ns/dymo_um.h:65:0: warning: "ntohl" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define ntohl(x) x
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:22:0,
                 from ./config.h:151,
                 from ./common/packet.h:43,
                 from trace/cmu-trace.cc:40:
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:400:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #   define ntohl(x) __bswap_32 (x)
 ^
In file included from trace/cmu-trace.cc:57:0:
./dymoum/ns/dymo_um.h:66:0: warning: "htonl" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define htonl(x) x
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:22:0,
                 from ./config.h:151,
                 from ./common/packet.h:43,
                 from trace/cmu-trace.cc:40:
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:402:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #   define htonl(x) __bswap_32 (x)
 ^
In file included from trace/cmu-trace.cc:57:0:
./dymoum/ns/dymo_um.h:67:0: warning: "htons" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define htons(x) x
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:22:0,
                 from ./config.h:151,
                 from ./common/packet.h:43,
                 from trace/cmu-trace.cc:40:
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:403:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #   define htons(x) __bswap_16 (x)
 ^
In file included from trace/cmu-trace.cc:57:0:
./dymoum/ns/dymo_um.h:68:0: warning: "ntohs" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define ntohs(x) x
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:22:0,
                 from ./config.h:151,
                 from ./common/packet.h:43,
                 from trace/cmu-trace.cc:40:
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:401:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #   define ntohs(x) __bswap_16 (x)
 ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc: In member function ‘void CMUTrace::format_olsr(Packet*, int)’:
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1462:2: error: ‘OLSR_pkt’ was not declared in this scope
  OLSR_pkt* op = PKT_OLSR(p);
  ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1462:12: error: ‘op’ was not declared in this scope
  OLSR_pkt* op = PKT_OLSR(p);
            ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1462:27: error: ‘PKT_OLSR’ was not declared in this scope
  OLSR_pkt* op = PKT_OLSR(p);
                           ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1473:33: error: ‘OLSR_HELLO_MSG’ was not declared in this scope
    if (op->msg(i).msg_type() == OLSR_HELLO_MSG)
                                 ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1475:38: error: ‘OLSR_TC_MSG’ was not declared in this scope
    else if (op->msg(i).msg_type() == OLSR_TC_MSG)
                                      ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1495:33: error: ‘OLSR_HELLO_MSG’ was not declared in this scope
    if (op->msg(i).msg_type() == OLSR_HELLO_MSG)
                                 ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1497:38: error: ‘OLSR_TC_MSG’ was not declared in this scope
    else if (op->msg(i).msg_type() == OLSR_TC_MSG)
                                      ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1517:33: error: ‘OLSR_HELLO_MSG’ was not declared in this scope
    if (op->msg(i).msg_type() == OLSR_HELLO_MSG)
                                 ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1519:38: error: ‘OLSR_TC_MSG’ was not declared in this scope
    else if (op->msg(i).msg_type() == OLSR_TC_MSG)
                                      ^
make: *** [trace/cmu-trace.o] Error 1
Ns make failed!*
```

i can't solve this error .I tried my best but i failed ...Kindly anyone look at the code and help me to solve error.The error code is given above:

Is error occurs in the presence of DYMOUM protocol?
If that is the issue how to solve this error?

Comment: May be OLSR conflicts with DYMOUM. ... Another thing : Did you see the changes required for adding {blackholeAODV + idsAODV + Dymoum} to ns-2.35/ ? → The edited Dymoum answer. ... About OLSR : I will look into it ... tomorrow.

Comment: By removing DYMOUM the OLSR running perfectly.But in presence of DYMOUM protocol the OLSR showing the above errors and same thing happens with DYMOUM.

Comment: After patching and installation of blackholeAODV + idsAODV + Dymo um  the ns make file got successful but then adding and giving ./install command for OLSR  the errors are shown above

Comment: **?** Why do you want the trouble adding two main routing protocols to the same ns-2.35? ... Like you wouldn't use AODV and OLSR in the same simulation, I guess. See the "90 times ns2" example setup : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12OSMRdV_aq4BXwEbXyuvsPSzWc86kwcF/view?usp=sharing